# How to create 4m x 4m survey grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I am trying to build a 4 km2 grid comprised of 4m x 4m squares in QGIS using the vector grid tool. However, in the parameters section of the vector grid window, I am unable to enter values less than 0.0001.

Is this a built-in limitation? Is there another way I should be trying to build such a grid?

Comment: Use a projected CRS in meters (like UTM), not a geographic CRS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find that the 0.0001 default is misleading. If you are using UTM, then the default values are in metres and this number represents less than a mm.

If you need a 4m x 4m grid, change that value to 4.